# Jelastic: any plan to support ed25519 ssh keys?

Tags: jelastic, ed25519

If I try to use a SSH key in the format of `ed25519` it tells it's invalid:

[image]

Jelastic version: `5.7`

Does Jelastic team plan to support such ssh-key format in the future?

Comment: Our plans depend on demands. ed25519 is not supported yet since we had no requests for it. Could you please share your point of view about why not using just RSA?

Comment: clarification: RSA 3072 or 4096-bit length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we're going to add ed25519 keys support. Delivery time is undefined and subject to change based on the requests, so push your hosting provider to get ed25519 support sooner.